# How to define correctly the column break in jasperreport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a fully dynamic report, and all columns generate by it are dynamic. By this i want to set a maximun value of columns per page. I searched for, and i found the COLUMN_BREAK element,but all the things that I do don't return the expected result. I try using PrintWhenExpression propertie,but don't work correctly. If anyone can explain me what i have to do.

Thanks!!!